# 'n' boost::thread instances doing 'm' jobs

Tags: c++, boost-thread

I am writing an evolution code, where in each generation there are (say) 100 organisms and fitness calculation for each of them is a easily parallelize-able procedure. Now, I do not want to create 100 independent threads altogether and want to decide this number (of simultaneously running threads) as a function of hardware concurrency (let's assume that number to be 8 for the moment).

The criteria I am imagining is I have to run a function (fitness function) on 100 organisms and with 8 threads running simultaneously.

Can anyone give me a simple but efficient way of doing it, using boost::thread_group? I am a bit confused with too many new concepts (Callback etc). So a simple c++ snippet would be greatly appreciated :)

TIA
regards,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the fitness function returns, much less does, but one idea would be to write a wrapper function around it that calls it "m" times -- in this case 100/8, or 12 times.  Then create a loop that loops "n" times, each time calling thread_group::add_thread, which spawns a new thread which calls the wrapper function.

The basic idea would be something like this:

```
/* ??? */ fitness_calculation(organism& o){
    //...
}

// wrapper function
void calc(std::vector<organism>& v, int idx, int loops){
    for(int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        fitness_calculation(v[idx + i]);    

}

int main(){
    int num_organisms = 100;
    std::vector<organism> v(num_organisms); // some array with the organisms

    int threads = 8;
    boost::thread_group g;
    int organisms_per_thread = num_organisms / threads;

    int i = 0, idx = 0;
    for (  ; i < threads; ++i, idx += organisms_per_thread )
        g.add_thread(calc, v, idx, organisms_per_thread);

    // finish up remainder in this thread
    calc(v, idx, num_organisms % threads);
    g.join_all();
}
```

I am not sure if I have the thread_group function call syntax right but its close enough.  Hopefully this helps.